# Select Data Frame result based on row occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following DataFrame how can I retrieve only the values where IS_TESTED has both True and False values.

```
d = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[700,700,701,702,702,703],"IS_TESTED":[True,False,True,False,True,True],"TEST_NAME":["A","B","A","A","B","A"]})
```

[image]

In the following example, my desired result should be:

```
700 True  A 
700 False B 
702 False A 
702 True  B
```

since 701 & 703 occurs only once.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use groupby and nunique

```
d[d.groupby('ID').IS_TESTED.transform('nunique') > 1]


    ID.         IS_TESTED   TEST_NAME
0   700         True         A
1   700         False        B
3   702         False        A
4   702         True         B
```

Answer (score 3):

Or, you can use `groupby` with `filter`:

```
d.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: x.IS_TESTED.nunique() > 1)
```

Output:

```
    ID  IS_TESTED TEST_NAME
0  700       True         A
1  700      False         B
3  702      False         A
4  702       True         B
```